# Identity Server Invalid Request Because Of Http Redirection

Tags: identityserver4

I am using .net core mvc as identity server client application. When going to the identity server in localhost, the redirect uri goes as https and connects, no problem. But it goes as http on the test server. And cause it is defined as https on the identity server, invalid request returns. How do I make this http part https?

Eror picture:
[https://ibb.co/2k2LK5j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RERfW.png)

I am using UserHttpsRedirection()

I marked with ** related parts in requests.

Working request:

> https://test.identityserversite.com/im/connect/authorize?client_id=bla_bla_client&redirect_uri=**https**://localhost:5001/signin-oidc&response_type=id_token
> token&scope=openid
> profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637975263254748013.MTUyNTc5OTgtYmJlMS00ZTAyLTgxMjAtNTNjZDNmZDBjMjY3MWIyNzg2ZDEtNmE1OS00NTUyLWEwNWMtNDI1N2ZiODAwMGVk&state=CfDJ8N9E0C7WvvpEoty-MgpSP4cRET_Y6sOuFDy58PjxCQcyD64gal_CBwXNx6DbTf7FyF8sQ9sJxeGZH1dAQPRn6mVHvUULG3FFz99XW7O9fpq8lTRvDSSxmBMoyBmSt4KwjbXdE60mbnllnlC7kbWT1ytqArRRKj8YtzkGQp2eg69TbuTJkgwIJsnFFbsfZ0Uo0A9xdYBP7eQRuMi9HrCZ6RU8l28E-U4fByg5Qzss2dcmLJDhPxWJd94z17MJwgEK6d1L34Kivc33NsGhXtwvFSypp6m2sgkSR3fT_bwvH-yy&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.10.0.0

Not Working request:

> https://test.identityserversite.com/im/connect/authorize?client_id=bla_bla_client&redirect_uri=**http**://clienttestsite.com/signin-oidc&response_type=id_token
> token&scope=openid
> profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637975265040994314.NmNiY2Q1MWQtOGJmYy00OWE0LTgxNGMtODk5MjkyY2QwOGNhYTJkMzdlZmItMzI4Ny00NmFkLTg3YjgtYjA4M2UzZDQ5OGZj&state=CfDJ8BWH8w1S3EBHujbHFc1L6rvNMx0jXRaUdB5aDFJ5wMA4IF5h17dNCV78tPAPLThXL6lS937Rz6mt3Jrbhn1cjozAeIL4bFu5YRkQLQeBKdGeAYA2Ikh610MqPSrG7bnCezbpdKrsGVNIKYZqIBuECh_gEm45T_b5HcuhzucF2du1Cz8sDtDmDzYKuSjBUo49b4-YNxM1zkGH8v2dkWxhNpduYYMQJwV53yy_BogGgaaT_8i9bffFKl_rYfOgtNAiw2OzZRpEqaqdvjCNQEetaNPcNnZiJYBEnloBSeG73njLAHIEoWD-OveWAT5-216OBw&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.10.0.0

**Error Update**:
We must use server as http without ssl behind the load balancer by company policy.
We have conf page like this:

```
options.Authority = identitySettings.Issuer;
        options.ClientId = identitySettings.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = identitySettings.ClientSecret;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "given_name";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("s_hash");


        //options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/account/accessdenied";
        //options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/account/accessdenied";

        Func<RedirectContext, Task> redirectToIdentityProvider = (ctx) =>
        {
            if (!ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.StartsWith("https"))
                ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http", "https");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        };
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = redirectToIdentityProvider
        };
        // this code changes http redirectUri to https redirectUri

        options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        //options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        //options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = "9cd9c695-cd02-4b70-a10b-df669cd77ed8";
        options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
        options.Scope.Clear();
        var scopes = identitySettings.Scopes.Split(',');
        foreach (var scope in scopes)
        {
            options.Scope.Add(scope);
        }
```

When we send request from browser our site redirects to identity server with http(issue at top). Identity server wants us to come with https. First identity server return us to "invalid reqquest". Cause allowedRedirectUri is "https:localhost:5001" So we manipulate the redirectUri http to https.(with event OnRedirectToIdentityProvider . You can see on top code). Now our site returns "correlation failed".

**UPDATE**
Type of our problem has been changed in a while. We figured out problen at the top with assigning ssl to server, not only load balancer.

Comment: could you remove redirectToIdentityProvider parts and run the client as https and give the feedback here

Comment: also remove these options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to use OpenID connect over HTTP using a browser. Why? Besides security, the browsers will not accept the cookies involved when sent over HTTP.

This is due to the samesite=none attribute set on some of the cookies. Browsers will reject these cookies if sent over HTTP.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Hey Tore thanks for your answer. Our company has policy about that we must use http without ssl behind the load balancer. We solved upper problem but halfway. ;How we fix? We change http to https at OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event. Now we can reach site but after login .../signin-oidc address gives an "correlation failed" error.

Comment: if you get correlation failed, then you need to also make sure you have configured the data protection api properly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-6.0
if you have multiple instances then all that should share the same cookies needs to use the same key

Comment: Hey @Tore i updated the question. Can you review? Thank for your  helpful interest. Also added dataProtection to program.cs but no help

Comment: What error do you get in IdenityServer logs?

Comment: have you read https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/deployment/proxies/ ?

Comment: Sorry @Tore i ve been working on this for days. We can login with identity server. And It sends us two cookie correlation and nonce. Then our app creates 8 piece cookie for identity and security. Then when browser send a request with headers included cookies, page response is can't  reach this page. Ssl does not appear. It is same on test server and local iis express. But on local kestrel works

Comment: Do you use HTTPS in the browser? Browsers will not include certain cookies over HTTP

Comment: It is https. Because it is redirecting and identity server conf can received only https domains. And login page is coming. Login is succesfull. Two cookies are coming to our app.

Comment: you need to write a more specific question about your problem.

Comment: You are right. I ll write clean question. Its type has been changed in a while.

Answer (score 0):

- **HTTP problem**
  your client seems in development since it is on local host. the client will deploy as http service behind reverse proxy and the domain/subdomains is configured with ssl in the front as your identity is referred as https address. (SSL offloading)

> https://test.identityserversite.com

so i dont think you have any problem in that. my services including identity server are http behind reverse proxy and i have subdomain with ssl configuration in nginx and i dont have any problem. and ofcourse for dployment you configure forward headers.

- **Corelation**
  in my case it happens when i played around samesite cookies.the configurations for cookie are mismatch between identity server and the client. i was able to reach login but after login i got the error.but it seems you stay samesite to none i guess. how ever it is mostly related to you cookies between client and identityserver

Comment: Thanks @rouzbeh i took benefits ffrom this answer when researching. . i ve been working on this for days. We can login with identity server. And It sends us two cookie correlation and nonce. Then our app creates 8 piece cookie for identity and security. Then when browser send a request with headers included cookies, page response is can't reach this page. Ssl does not appear. It is same on test server and local iis express. But on local kestrel works –